# Is there anyway to take the ith element of a list in time o(1) Standard ML

Tags: functional-programming, sml

I would like to ask you if there is an efficient way to take a specific element of a list ( specifically in o(1) ). As I can understand the nth function needs o(n) and so it is not appropriate for the job that I have to do.

Comment: No, this is not possible. SML lists are linked lists -- which have O(n) access. On the other hand, there *are* data structures in SML with O(1) access -- but those are not lists.

Comment: @JohnColeman thank for your answer!Can you propose me a data structure for this job? For example does Array need O(1) ?

Comment: Look into the Vector structure in the standard basis library. Also -- why did you tag this question with `haskell`? The question seems to be 100% SML Using `ssml` is even worse -- please read the description of a tag before deciding to use it, and use it only when truly appropriate. You can edit the tags here.

Comment: @JohnColeman Thank you for your answer ! I tag with haskell  because is also functional language and probably someone with haskell knowledge knows also SML and as a result can reply to my question. As i understand i have to be 100% strict about tags ( sorry i am very new here ) . Thank you again for your answer!

Comment: Using the functional programming tag covers that. Most people who follow the haskell and sml tags probably follow the functional-programming tag as well.

Comment: Thank you for telling me this . I will be more carefull the next time. By the way , with vectors my implementation works great. You help me a lot! THANK YOU SO MUCH!